# Issue on Clearing/ Removing Google Maps Infobox (Custom InfoWindow)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobox

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://codepen.io/behseini/pen/EavVxe) and let me know why I am not able:

1- To close any open infoBox when a new one opens

2- Clear/ Remove open infoBox when user clicks on Clear button?

Here is the code I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var markers = []; // makers array
  var infoBox = null;
    var myOptions = { // map settings
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.721759, -9.151692),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        sensor: 'true'
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("canvas-map"), myOptions);

    var data = [ // map data
    {
        id: 1,
        content: '<div class="img"></div><div class="txt"><h1>THIS TITLE</h1><span>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Donec sed odio dui. Donec sed odio dui. Aenean eu leo quam.</span></div><div class="fot"></div>',
        position: {
            lat: 38.721759,
            lng: -9.151692
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        content: '<div class="img"></div><div class="txt"><h1>THIS TITLE</h1><span>This is a test.</span></div><div class="fot"></div>',
        position: {
            lat: 38.720805,
            lng: -9.146585
        }
    }
    ]

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var current = data[i];

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(current.position.lat, current.position.lng),
            map: map,
            content: current.content
        });

        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function(e) {
              infoBox = new InfoBox({
                latlng: this.getPosition(),
                map: map,
                content: this.content
            });
        });
    }


   function clearMap(){
    for(i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
            markers = [];   
         infoBox.close();
    }

   $("#clear").on("click",function(){
       clearMap();
    });   
});
```

As you can see I already tried

```
 infoBox.close();
```

which I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` for `.close()` I also tried the `.remove()` which removes the info box from map but when zoom in or out the box appears again at the map!

for closing the existing infobox also I tried the

```
 if (infoBox) {
            infoBox.close();
      }
```

in the following cod but it didn't do the job either!

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function(e) {
 if (infoBox) {
        infoBox.close();
  }
          infoBox = new InfoBox({
            latlng: this.getPosition(),
            map: map,
            content: this.content
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ce7z2e41/1/) with code from your link has infoBoxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your infoBox doesn't have a .close() method, use .setMap(null) instead.
2. If you want to only have one InfoBox, only create one (the first time it is opened, as it needs a latlng), and move it to the appropriate marker.  Requires writing a method to "move" the InfoBox

click listener that "moves" the InfoBox:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function (e) {
    if (!infoBox) {
        infoBox = new InfoBox({
            latlng: this.getPosition(),
            map: map,
            content: this.content
        });
    } else {
        infoBox.setOptions({
            map: map,
            content: this.content
        });
        infoBox.setPosition(this.getPosition());
    }
});

/* move the InfoBox
 */
InfoBox.prototype.setPosition = function(latlng) {
    this.latlng_ = latlng;
};
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ce7z2e41/2/)