# zoom out when infoBox is closed and only one info box open at a time Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

- Question One: When closing an "infobox" how can I make it maps zoom back out?
- Question Two: How would I make it so that only one "infobox" is open at a time?

I have tried adding:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
    if (! markers.length) { return; }
    for (i in markers) {
       markers[i].infoBox.close();
    }
});
```

However the code dose not seem to work. Any thoughts?

```
function InfoBox(opts) {
    google.maps.OverlayView.call(this);
    this.latlng_ = opts.latlng;
    this.map_ = opts.map;
    this.content = opts.content;
    this.offsetVertical_ = -195;
    this.offsetHorizontal_ = 5;
    this.height_ = 165;
    this.width_ = 266;
    var me = this;
    this.boundsChangedListener_ =
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, "bounds_changed", function () {
            return me.panMap.apply(me);

        });

    this.setMap(this.map_);
}

InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

InfoBox.prototype.remove = function () {
    if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
        this.div_ = null;
    }
};


    this.createElement();
    if (!this.div_) return;

    var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
    if (!pixPosition) return;

    this.div_.style.width = this.width_ + "px";
    this.div_.style.left = (pixPosition.x + this.offsetHorizontal_) + "px";
    this.div_.style.height = this.height_ + "px";
    this.div_.style.top = (pixPosition.y + this.offsetVertical_) + "px";
    this.div_.style.display = 'block';
};

InfoBox.prototype.createElement = function () {
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    var div = this.div_;
    if (!div) {

        div = this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "infobox"
        var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
            contentDiv.className = "content"
            contentDiv.innerHTML = this.content;
        var closeBox = document.createElement("div");
            closeBox.className = "close";
            closeBox.innerHTML = "x";
        div.appendChild(closeBox);

        function removeInfoBox(ib) {
            return function () {
                ib.setMap(null);
            };
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeBox, 'click', removeInfoBox(this));
        div.appendChild(contentDiv);
        div.style.display = 'none';
        panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
        this.panMap();
    } else if (div.parentNode != panes.floatPane) {

        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
    } else {

       .
    }
}

InfoBox.prototype.panMap = function () {

    var map = this.map_;
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    if (!bounds) return;

    var position = this.latlng_;

    var iwWidth = this.width_;
    var iwHeight = this.height_;

    var iwOffsetX = this.offsetHorizontal_;
    var iwOffsetY = this.offsetVertical_;

    var padX = 40;
    var padY = 40;

    var mapDiv = map.getDiv();
    var mapWidth = mapDiv.offsetWidth;
    var mapHeight = mapDiv.offsetHeight;
    var boundsSpan = bounds.toSpan();
    var longSpan = boundsSpan.lng();
    var latSpan = boundsSpan.lat();
    var degPixelX = longSpan / mapWidth;
    var degPixelY = latSpan / mapHeight;

    var mapWestLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
    var mapEastLng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
    var mapNorthLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    var mapSouthLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();

    var iwWestLng = position.lng() + (iwOffsetX - padX) * degPixelX;
    var iwEastLng = position.lng() + (iwOffsetX + iwWidth + padX) * degPixelX;
    var iwNorthLat = position.lat() - (iwOffsetY - padY) * degPixelY;
    var iwSouthLat = position.lat() - (iwOffsetY + iwHeight + padY) * degPixelY;

    var shiftLng =
        (iwWestLng < mapWestLng ? mapWestLng - iwWestLng : 0) +
        (iwEastLng > mapEastLng ? mapEastLng - iwEastLng : 0);
    var shiftLat =
        (iwNorthLat > mapNorthLat ? mapNorthLat - iwNorthLat : 0) +
        (iwSouthLat < mapSouthLat ? mapSouthLat - iwSouthLat : 0);

    var center = map.getCenter();

    var centerX = center.lng() - shiftLng;
    var centerY = center.lat() - shiftLat;

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(centerY, centerX));

    google.maps.event.removeListener(this.boundsChangedListener_);
    this.boundsChangedListener_ = null;
};

function initialize() {
    var markers = []; 

    var myOptions = { 
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-5.646, 20.0611),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        sensor: 'true'
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("canvas-map"), myOptions);

    var data = [ 
      {
        'id':1,
        'content':'Hello my name is marker, I\'m from Google',
        'position': {
          'lat':-33,
          'lng':150
         }
      },
      {
        'id':2,
        'content':'I am the content of this infobox. Wow, what a text.<br><br><a href="#">The good thing is: Tags are also possible</a>',
        'position': {
          'lat':-34,
          'lng':150
         }
      },
    ]

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var current = data[i];

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(current.position.lat, current.position.lng),
        map: map,
        content: current.content
      });

      markers.push(marker);
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
          map.setZoom(8);
          map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

        });

      google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function (e) {       
           map.zoomOut(); 
           map.setCenter(this.getPosition()); 
        var infoBox = new InfoBox({
            latlng: this.getPosition(),
            map: map,
            content: this.content           
        });

      });

    }


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue on Clearing/ Removing Google Maps Infobox (Custom InfoWindow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179773/issue-on-clearing-removing-google-maps-infobox-custom-infowindow)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map V3 - Allow only one infobox to be displayed at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908132/google-map-v3-allow-only-one-infobox-to-be-displayed-at-a-time)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to question 1

If you want the map to zoom out when the user closes an info window, you can listen for the `closeclick` event on the info window object.

```
infoWindow.addListener('closeclick', function() {
  map.setZoom(3); // Set the desired zoom level
});
```

I couldn't get your code to work so I created a [basic example](http://jsbin.com/favuxuq/4/edit?js,output) of the above functionality in action. Clicking on the marker opens an info window and zooms the map in. Closing the info window, zooms the map back out.

### Answer to question 2

Check out geocodezip's comments to your question. He provides [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179773/issue-on-clearing-removing-google-maps-infobox-custom-infowindow) to [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908132/google-map-v3-allow-only-one-infobox-to-be-displayed-at-a-time) that could help you figure out how to have only one info window open at a time.